# Efficiently changing the date format of an existing log file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a log file which runs in to gigabytes in size which I parse into a csv file which is used for processing and data analysis. While creating the csv file I want the date to be in a particular format.

Input file:

```
Apr 22 23:08:26 a,x,y
Apr 22 23:08:26 b,y,z
Apr 22 23:08:26 c,s,s
```

Output file:

```
20140422,23:08:26,a,x,y
20140422,23:08:26,b,y,z
20140422,23:08:26,c,s,s
```

Currently I'm doing this using the following awk statement - but it takes hours to run through a file which is more than a gigabyte in size.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {getDate="date -f \"%b %d %H:%M:%S\" \""$1" "$2" "$3"\" \"+%Y%m%d\",\"%H:%M:%S\""
while ( ( getDate | getline date ) > 0 ) { }
close(getDate);
print date,$4}' inputFile
```

Could this be further optimized? Is awk the right tool to use here?

Comment: Have you considered using a scalable logging solution such as logstash, elasticsearch, redis, and kibana?

Comment: @egorulz how you would know from Input that it's 2014? which you expect in outfile!

Comment: @Jord I'm thinking of fetching the year field from the last modified time on the original log file.

Comment: @staticx I'm considering a number of logging solutions right now and am open to suggestions. Ned to read up on redis and kibana, never heard of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the `date` command once per line for millions of lines is going to be painfully slow.  Anything that avoids that is going to be faster.  One answer has suggested `sed` — that has many merits; another suggested Perl — ditto.

Using `awk`, you could look at:

```
awk 'BEGIN { m["Jan"] = "01"; m["Feb"] = "02"; m["Mar"] = "03";
             m["Apr"] = "04"; m["May"] = "05"; m["Jun"] = "06";
             m["Jul"] = "07"; m["Aug"] = "08"; m["Sep"] = "09";
             m["Oct"] = "10"; m["Nov"] = "11"; m["Dec"] = "12";
           }
           {
             printf "2014%s%02d,%s,", m[$1], $2, $3;
             pad=""
             for (i = 4; i <= NF; i++) { printf("%s%s", pad, $i); pad = " " }
             printf "\n"
           }
    ' log-file
```

If you have GNU `awk`, it has time manipulation functions built in, though frankly treating the date information as strings and numbers as shown is quite as effective.

Given an input log file like this:

```
Apr 22 23:08:26 a,x,y
Apr 22 23:08:26 b,y,z
Apr 22 23:08:26 c,s,s
Jan 31 00:19:50 c,info with spaces,some more info
Feb  2 00:20:41 c,info with spaces,some more info
Mar 13 00:31:32 c,info with spaces,some more info
May  5 00:42:23 c,info with spaces,some more info
Jun 16 00:53:14 c,info with spaces,some more info
Jul 27 00:04:05 c,info with spaces,some more info
Aug  8 00:15:56 c,info with spaces,some more info
Sep 29 00:26:47 c,info with spaces,some more info
Oct 30 00:37:38 c,info with spaces,some more info
Nov 12 00:49:29 c,info with spaces,some more info
Dec 22 00:50:10 c,info with spaces,some more info
```

It generates output like this:

```
20140422,23:08:26,a,x,y
20140422,23:08:26,b,y,z
20140422,23:08:26,c,s,s
20140131,00:19:50,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140202,00:20:41,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140313,00:31:32,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140505,00:42:23,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140616,00:53:14,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140727,00:04:05,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140808,00:15:56,c,info with spaces,some more info
20140929,00:26:47,c,info with spaces,some more info
20141030,00:37:38,c,info with spaces,some more info
20141112,00:49:29,c,info with spaces,some more info
20141222,00:50:10,c,info with spaces,some more info
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try a (assuming this is always for this year) :

```
sed -e 's/\(:[0-9]\{2\}\) /\1,/
s/^Jan \([0-9]*\) /201401\1,/;t
s/^Feb \([0-9]*\) /201402\1,/;t
s/^Mar \([0-9]*\) /201403\1,/;t
s/^Apr \([0-9]*\) /201404\1,/;t
s/^May \([0-9]*\) /201405\1,/;t
s/^Jun \([0-9]*\) /201406\1,/;t
s/^Jul \([0-9]*\) /201407\1,/;t
s/^Aug \([0-9]*\) /201408\1,/;t
s/^Sep \([0-9]*\) /201409\1,/;t
s/^Oct \([0-9]*\) /201410\1,/;t
s/^Nov \([0-9]*\) /201411\1,/;t
s/^Dec \([0-9]*\) /201412\1,/' YourFile
```

`t` is an optimization when a substitution is occuring, not needed to test another one on the same line. For pure performance you could remove line that are not used (if you only have a log having 1 or 2  month, not needed to test other one).

Comment: Nice.  It might be worth anchoring the matches to the start of line with `s/^Jan …/…/`, etc.  In English, it is `Feb` rather than `Fev`; French at least would use `Fev`, and quite possibly some other languages too. You also need to insert a comma after the time.

Comment: perfect for doing JUST that!

Comment: `^`not needed if no  month pattern are in later data. I adapt the script, sorry for fev, ...

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't tag with perl, perhaps it isn't an option but personally I would consider using it. You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

{
    open my $in, "<", "logfile" or die "couldn't open logfile: $!";
    open my $out, ">", "new_logfile" or die "couldn't open new_logfile: $!";

    while(<$in>) {
        my @cols = split;
        my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("$cols[0] $cols[1] 2014", "%b %e %Y");
        print $out join(",", ($t->strftime("%Y%m%d"),@cols[2,-1])),"\n";
    }
}
```

This uses the core [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module to parse the times in your log file and convert them to the format you require. Using perl without calling any external functions is likely to be a lot faster than what you have currently. I hard-coded the year 2014 because I'm not sure where else it would come from.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {

    OFS=","
}

{
    i = index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", $1)

    m = sprintf ("%02d", ((i - 1) / 3) + 1)

    print "2014" m $2, $3, $4
}
```

Results:

```
20140422,23:08:26,a,x,y
20140422,23:08:26,b,y,z
20140422,23:08:26,c,s,s
```